# What does "user_friends" column in Twitter API library mean?

Tags: api, twitter, powerbi, sentiment-analysis

I am pulling data from Twitter API Library to create some sentiment analysis reports. I have a column called "user_friends".
Twitter has no concept of friends. There are only followers. So can anybody explain me what this "user_friends" column means?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there also a user_followers column? And do they contain lists of ids, or just a count? It might be helpful to post a sample row of your data.

Answer (score 0):

In the Twitter API, a "friend" is someone that the specified user is following.

This information is the very first sentence on the [GET friends/ids page](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/ids) in the [Twitter REST API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public).